# Trying to reverse a linked list using recursion and pointer to pointer but reversell function not giving expected proper output

Tags: c++, pointers, recursion, linked-list, pointer-to-pointer

I was trying to reverse a linked list using recursion and pointer to pointer but reversell function is not working properly as expected. Only reversell function has some problem all other functions are working totally fine. I have used pointer to pointer in insertlast function also and it is working correctly.

Actually i am following 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KYH83T4q6Vs&list=PL2_aWCzGMAwI3W_JlcBbtYTwiQSsOTa6P&index=11
This video but I tried using pointer to pointer. The code shown in video didn't use pointer to pointer. He has used head as global variable.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct node{
    int data;
    struct node* next;
};

void print(node* head){
    while(head !=  NULL){
        cout<<head->data<<" ";
        head=head->next;
    }
}

void reversell(node** head){
    node* temp = (*head);
    if(temp->next == NULL){
        (*head)=temp;
        return;
    }
    reversell(&(temp->next));
    node* temp1 = temp->next;
    temp1->next = temp;
    temp->next = NULL;

}

void insertlast(node** head,int x){
    node* temp = new node;
    temp->data=x;
    if((*head)==NULL){
        (*head)=temp;
        temp->next=NULL;
        return;
    }
    node* temp1=(*head);
    while((temp1->next) != NULL){
        temp1=temp1->next;
    }
    temp1->next=temp;
    temp->next=NULL;
}

int main()
{
    cout<<"How many numbers do you want to add to linked list"<<endl;
    int x;
    cin>>x;
    node* head=NULL;
    cout<<"Please Enter your numbers now"<<endl;
    for (int i=0;i<x;i++){
        int num;
        cin>>num;
        insertlast(&head,num);
    }
    print(head);
    cout<<endl;
    reversell(&head);
    print(head);
    return 0;
}
```

I am currently getting output as shown below:

How many numbers do you want to add to linked list

5

Please Enter your numbers now

1 2 3 4 5

1 2 3 4 5

1

Process finished with exit code 0

Expected output is:

How many numbers do you want to add to linked list

5

Please Enter your numbers now

1 2 3 4 5

1 2 3 4 5

5 4 3 2 1

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: The logic in `reversell` just seems wrong. You recursively sort the rest of the list, and then add the first item to the beginning of the (allegedly) reversed list. Obviously the result is no change. Maybe if you followed the recursive call to `reverseall` with a call to `insertlast` it would work (albeit very inefficiently).

Comment: the logic is totally fine for clarification on logic you can watch youtube video given above. In video He has used same logic but he didn't use pointer to pointer. He has declared head as global variable.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
node *reverse (node *head) {
    // 2) reach the last element and return it
    if(head->next == NULL) {
        return head;
    } else {
        // 1) run revers for tail of our list
        node *new_head = reverse(head->next);
        // 3) relocate pointers
        // new_head = 5;
        // head = 4, head->next = 5, head->next->next = null
        head->next->next = head; // after this line head = 4, head->next = 5, head->next->next = 4
        head->next = NULL; // after this line head = 4, head->next = null, head->next->next = 4
        return new_head; // new_head = 5, new_head->next = 4 similarly recursion takes place further
    }
}
```

And then:

```
head = reverse (head);
print(head);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function `reversell` is partial ok, but you missing to keep the output. You can try this:

```
void reverse(node* head, node **headRef)
{
    node* firstTemp = NULL;
    node* secondTemp = NULL;

    //empty list
    if(!head)
        return;

    firstTemp = head;
    secondTemp = firstTemp->next;

    //list has only one node
    if(!secondTemp)
    {
         *headRef = firstTemp;
         return;
    }

    reverse(secondTemp, headRef);

    secondTemp->next = firstTemp;
    firstTemp->next = NULL;
}

void reversell(node **head)
{
     reverse(*head, head);
}
```